# Days remaining from start date is showing incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that displays an item that a user wants to sell. In one columns of the repeater,  the `CreateDate` or the date the item was posted is displayed like so:

```
        //lblExp.Text originally contains 2013-05-24 14:24:08.000

        Label lblExp = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblExp");
        DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblExp.Text);

        DateTime expDate = StartDate.AddDays(30);
        int DaysLeft = (expDate - StartDate).Days;
        lblExp.Text = DaysLeft.ToString();
```

When that code executes I get 30 instead of 28.

Comment: Why were you expecting to get 28?

Comment: You just made `expDate` equal `StartDate` + 30 days.  Why do you expect `expDate - StartDate` to be 28?

Comment: well, i figured it would minus the day it was now from the start date. but I forgot to factor in the `Now()` part. haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to say? (replacing `StartDate` with `DateTime.Now`)

```
    //lblExp.Text originally contains 2013-05-24 14:24:08.000

    Label lblExp = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblExp");
    DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblExp.Text);

    DateTime expDate = StartDate.AddDays(30);
    int DaysLeft = (expDate - DateTime.Now).Days; // Replaced here
    lblExp.Text = DaysLeft.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks Gjeltema, I think I had been staring at it too long. I wanted to get where I was in the date and forgot all about factoring in the `Now()`.